# customize field name to be used on find method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way to customize the field name used in the find method in laravel:

```
User::find(1) //this assumes that the primary key field is always named id
```

I tried doing this on the model:

```
public static $id = 'user_id';
```

But this doesn't work. The query that it uses when doing find() is still using the column 'id'

I can always do something like:

```
$user = User::where('user_id', '=', 2);
```

But I like typing less code and I specifically want to chain it to insert a new record to another table but this doesn't work:

```
$user = User::where('insect_id', '=', 2)->transactions()->insert(array('trans_id' => 34));
```

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE::** (11 nov  2013)

As of laravel 4, primaryKey needs to be overridden to access the primary key attribute.

[reference](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage)

Example :

> protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

**OLD::**

use

```
public static $key = 'user_id';
```

in your model

See http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Laravel.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#45 for details...